# Using Scanf with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I am fairly new to C and I am having trouble using `scanf` with pointers. I have been told to get user inputs for 3 `int` and 1 `char` values and then print them back out using pointers.

This is the best I could come up with so far:

```
int a, b, c;
char d;
int *x = &a;
int *y = &b;
int *z = &c;
char *e = &d;

scanf("Enter 3 Ints and 1 Char:%d %d %d %c", x, y, z, e);
printf("The numbers are:\n");
printf("%d\n %d\n %d\n %c\n", a, b, c, d);

return 0;
```

When I enter the values the following is printed out:

```
2 3 4 c
The numbers are:
32708
 -613084440
 32708
 �
```

Again, I'm very new to programming so I apologize if this is a stupid mistake or something obvious that I have missed.

Comment: Why don't you just do `scanf("Enter 3 Ints and 1 Char:%d %d %d %c", &a, &b, &c, &d);` in the first place? Is there any particular reason why you create those pointer variables first?

Comment: You're trying to include the prompt string in the `scanf` format string.  That won't work.  Your `scanf` will only work if you literally type `Enter 3 Ints and 1 Char:` at the start of your input, which isn't what you want.  Also, check and print the return value from `scanf`.  That will tell you how many values it actually read.      Always check the return value from `scanf`, and take appropriate action if it's not what you expect.  Don't just ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not checking the return value of your `scanf`, otherwise you would know that it returns `0`, as in 'no elements read'.

Your scanf expects you to write exactly what you are putting in there, so, if you entered `Enter 3 Ints and 1 Char:2 3 4 c`, it would probably work.

What you want, however, is this:

```
printf("Enter 3 Ints and 1 Char: ");

if (scanf("%d %d %d %c", &a, &b, &c, &d) != 4)
    printf("Invalid input detected\n");
else
    printf("The numbers are:\n%d\n %d\n %d\n %c\n", a, b, c, d);
```

The first line will print the prompt to the console, the second will read the values into variables.

There is no need to create separate pointer variables for this purpose.

Comment: What do you mean by checking the return values from scanf?

Comment: @GrandadDouglas, `scanf` returns the number of values actually parsed successfully. I have amended the snippet to include 'return value checking' for clarity.

Comment: @GrandadDouglas `scanf` returns an integer, which is the number of fields it successfully scanned.  Compare that value to what you expect, and give an error if it doesn't match.

Comment: @GrandadDouglas Always look at the man page for a library function before using it.  In this case, it shows that `scanf` returns an `int`, and it describes what that return value is.  Never just ignore errors.  That's the road to buggy code that no one wants to use.

Comment: Glad I was able to help, @GrandadDouglas. Please don't forget to accept an answer, so others will know that you no longer require help, thank you.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Yep, sorry lol]